# beeline ( HiveServer2 ) not writing console logs when hive.exec.parallel is set to True

Tags: hive, cloudera

We've recently started using CDH 6.2 and hive-2.1.1. In Our existing jobs ( in old cluster ) we've set of properties that we set by default. In that one of the property we use is `hive.exec.parallel=true`.

In the new ( hive-2.1.1/ CDH 6.2.1) cluster when we run jobs with `hive.exec.parallel=true` beeline is not writing any console logs, which shows the status of the job, application URL and other info like below

```
INFO  : Running with YARN Application = application_1596901153465_0484
INFO  : Kill Command = /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.1-1.cdh6.2.1.p0.1425774/lib/hadoop/bin/yarn application -kill application_1596901153465_0484
INFO  : Hive on Spark Session Web UI URL: http://us-east-1a-test-east-cdh-tasknode670.throtle-test.internal:45956
INFO  :
Query Hive on Spark job[0] stages: [0, 1, 2]
INFO  : Spark job[0] status = RUNNING
INFO  : Job Progress Format
CurrentTime StageId_StageAttemptId: SucceededTasksCount(+RunningTasksCount-FailedTasksCount)/TotalTasksCount
INFO  : 2020-08-09 04:28:23,096 Stage-0_0: 0(+1)/3      Stage-1_0: 0/64 Stage-2_0: 0/64
INFO  : 2020-08-09 04:28:26,106 Stage-0_0: 0(+1)/3      Stage-1_0: 0/64 Stage-2_0: 0/64
INFO  : 2020-08-09 04:28:27,110 Stage-0_0: 0(+3)/3      Stage-1_0: 0/64 Stage-2_0: 0/64
```

I am able to get these logs **only if I disable** `hive.exec.parallel=true`

Can any one help me in getting console logs even with hive parallel execution?

Comment: run `beeline ${BEELINE_URL} -e 'set -v'  > session.txt` to validate the configs related to Tez,MR, Hive related logging properties and do trail & error and set the properties.

Comment: @smart_coder, Thanks for providing the commands, as you can see I was able to get the logs, but I don't know how to get logs even with `hive.exec.parallel=true`. It also looks like it's a known bug https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-22416

Comment: what is your hive version? -> https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-22416 issue got fixed in the 4.0.0 version of hive.

Comment: Hi @sathya, Thanks for pointing that it got fix in 4.0.0, Yes I also saw and unfortunately am not on 4.0.0 ( as mentioned in my original description ) but on Hive-2.1.1 ( in CDH 6.2). Please let me know if there is any other workaround than HIVE-22416